# My Python application doesn't communicate with MySQL inside docker. Can someone help me?

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, python, mysql

The connection is not succeeding in docker. Look at my settings:

Dockerfile

```
FROM python:3.8.5-alpine

WORKDIR /app

COPY requirements.txt .

RUN python3 -m pip install --upgrade pip

RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

COPY . .

CMD ["python3", "-m", "scraper"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
   version: '3'
    services:
      python_app:
        build:
          context: .
          dockerfile: Dockerfile
        ports:
          - '80:80'
        links:
          - 'mysql_db'
        depends_on:
          - mysql_db
        networks:
          - app-tier
    
      mysql_db:
        image: mysql:5.7
        ports:
          - '3307:3306'
        environment: 
          MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: 'flavio'
          MYSQL_DATABASE: 'Vestibular'
          MYSQL_USER: 'flavio'
          MYSQL_PASSWORD: ''
        networks:
          - app-tier
    
    networks:
      app-tier:
        driver: bridge
```

db.py

```
import mysql.connector

def insert_into_database(data):
    print("Salvando no banco de dados")
    aux = ""
    for i, item in enumerate(data):
        if i == len(data)-1:
            aux += str(item)
        else:
            aux += f"{str(item)}, "

    
    try:
        connection = mysql.connector.connect(host='localhost',
                                            database='Vestibular',
                                            user='flavio',
                                            password='')
        cursor = connection.cursor()

        stmt = "SHOW TABLES LIKE 'Candidates'"
        cursor.execute(stmt)
        result = cursor.fetchone()

        mySql_Create_Table_Query = """CREATE TABLE Candidates ( 
                             Id int(11) AUTO_INCREMENT NOT NULL,
                             Name varchar(250) NOT NULL,
                             Score varchar(250) NOT NULL,
                             PRIMARY KEY (Id)) """
        

        mySql_insert_query = f"""INSERT INTO Candidates (Name, Score) 
                            VALUES 
                            {aux}; """

        if not result:
            cursor.execute(mySql_Create_Table_Query)
        cursor.execute(mySql_insert_query)
        connection.commit()
        print(cursor.rowcount, "Record inserted successfully into Candidates table")
        cursor.close()

    except mysql.connector.Error as error:
        print("Failed to insert record into Candidates table {}".format(error))

    finally:
        if connection.is_connected():
            connection.close()
            print("MySQL connection is closed")
```

Answer (score 1):

The `python_app` and `mysql_db` services/containers do not share a network namespace, thus they don't have the same `localhost`. Just use `mysql_db` as the hostname when connecting to the DB.

I would recommend that your python code takes the DB hostname from an env var or command line argument. If you want to hardcode it, you can use something like `db` and then use the docker compose links aliasing feature which is documented [here](https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/#links) to map `db` to the actual service name.